# Ellipsize in Android

Tags: android, string, textview

I used the ellipsize attribute in TextView to add 3 dots (...) at the end of the long string. But it cause me a problem that ellipsize break in the middle of the word.

For example, I have a string "Android is an operating system based on the Linux kernel" and ellipsize gives me string "Android is an operating sys..." in TextView. The string I need is "Android is an operating system..." or "Android is an operating..." instead of breaking at the middle of the word. How could I solve this ? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid whether by implementing custom TextView or formatting the text on your own and using setText(formattedString) later on.

Comment: I faced with similar problem not long time ago and after looking at the source code discover that there is no possible way instead of creating own extending class

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution for this is ,you have to use custom TextView where you can set ellipsis at the end of complete word. You can have look on following code which i found in stack overflow .
"int lastSpace = workingText.lastIndexOf(' ')"
In the above line , this will find the index of last space which will be present in string workingText and  "..." will be appended end of it.

following is the whole code snippet just have look :

```
public class EllipsizingTextView extends TextView {
    private static final String ELLIPSIS = "...";

    public interface EllipsizeListener {
        void ellipsizeStateChanged(boolean ellipsized);
    }

    private final List<EllipsizeListener> ellipsizeListeners = new ArrayList<EllipsizeListener>();
    private boolean isEllipsized;
    private boolean isStale;
    private boolean programmaticChange;
    private String fullText;
    private int maxLines = -1;
    private float lineSpacingMultiplier = 1.0f;
    private float lineAdditionalVerticalPadding = 0.0f;

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EllipsizingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void addEllipsizeListener(EllipsizeListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        ellipsizeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeEllipsizeListener(EllipsizeListener listener) {
        ellipsizeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public boolean isEllipsized() {
        return isEllipsized;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(int maxLines) {
        super.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        this.maxLines = maxLines;
        isStale = true;
    }

    public int getMaxLines() {
        return maxLines;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (isStale) {
            super.setEllipsize(null);
            resetText();
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void resetText() {
        int maxLines = getMaxLines();
        String workingText = fullText;
        boolean ellipsized = false;
        if (maxLines != -1) {
            Layout layout = createWorkingLayout(workingText);
            if (layout.getLineCount() > maxLines) {
                workingText = fullText.substring(0, layout.getLineEnd(maxLines - 1)).trim();
                while (createWorkingLayout(workingText + ELLIPSIS).getLineCount() > maxLines) {
                    int lastSpace = workingText.lastIndexOf(' ');
                    if (lastSpace == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    workingText = workingText.substring(0, lastSpace);
                }
                workingText = workingText + ELLIPSIS;
                ellipsized = true;
            }
        }
        if (!workingText.equals(getText())) {
            programmaticChange = true;
            try {
                setText(workingText);
            } finally {
                programmaticChange = false;
            }
        }
        isStale = false;
        if (ellipsized != isEllipsized) {
            isEllipsized = ellipsized;
            for (EllipsizeListener listener : ellipsizeListeners) {
                listener.ellipsizeStateChanged(ellipsized);
            }
        }
    }

    private Layout createWorkingLayout(String workingText) {
        return new StaticLayout(workingText, getPaint(), getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight(),
                Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, lineSpacingMultiplier, lineAdditionalVerticalPadding, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEllipsize(TruncateAt where) {
        // Ellipsize settings are not respected
    }
}
```